# Why do I get an error deploying clojurescript 0.0-2665 app to Heroku, but not locally?

Tags: heroku, clojurescript

The web app runs perfectly in my local environment.  But when deploying to Heroku, it fails with this error:

```
Compiling "resources/public/js/main.js" failed. clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: failed compiling file:src/cljs/common/talks.cljs {:file #} at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4403)
...
Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such namespace: pts.common at line 1 src/cljs/common/talks.cljs {:tag :cljs/analysis-error, :file "src/cljs/common/talks.cljs", :line 1, :column 1}
... 
Uberjar aborting because jar failed: Subprocess failed ! Failed to build.
! Push rejected, failed to compile Clojure (Leiningen 2)
```

`pts.common` is including by several modules of clojurescript, and the reference is resolved under version 0.0-2511, though compilation will sometimes generate a warning but still succeed and run.

Comment: Can you include the source (or at least a snippet of the relevant portion)? I too have seen that an error to require a referenced namespace previously only resulted in a warning being emitted.

Comment: The build is failing on line 1, which is just the standard `ns` form.

Comment: Maybe it is a src path issue. (Just a guess that the analyzer can't find `pts.common`.)

Comment: See https://github.com/mfikes/weasel-src-paths

Comment: I gave that a shot, and I'm seeing the same error.  I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: Perhaps turning on [:verbose](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#verbose) may reveal a little more.